# How can I limit the number of login attempts on IIS for all IPs?

Tags: iis

How can I restrict the number of login attempts for our website hosted on IIS? Currently we're using Basic authentication but I'm open to using other authentication methods on IIS, or installing an application on the webserver to enable this feature.

I've looked at AspNetCoreRateLimit, however it appears that only helps restricting login attempts by IP address. I prefer all IPs to be able to attempt to authenticate and rate limit login attempts then take any action following failure.

Comment: That's what people use a firewall in front of their web server for. Don't do it on the IIS machine.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, IIS does not have a specific setting for limiting the maximum number of logins. Even if you use other authentication methods on IIS, none of them have functionality to limit the maximum number of logins.